# How to access internet on laptop from Blackberry 9300 curve mobile using Bluetooth connection

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet, bluetooth

Please help me to make an internet connection using Bluetooth in my laptop. I am using Blackberry curve 9300 and HP Probook 4440s with Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot establish an Internet Connection using Bluetooth. You can try it with the so called ["tethering"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering).

If you already knew it, but don't know if your Blackberry phone will support it, then check it on the web if possible. (Which is, the most probable thing to do when you don't know about something.)

I had also found something interesting on the web. Check: [tether.com](http://tether.com/).